# jQuery select next child element when class attributes are used

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<ul class="orderlines">
    <li class="orderline selected"></li>
    <li class="orderline"></li>
    <li class="orderline"></li>
</ul>
```

I want to click the element next to the orderline with the `selected` class attribute, so it becomes:

```
<ul class="orderlines">
    <li class="orderline "></li>
    <li class="orderline selected"></li>
    <li class="orderline"></li>
</ul>
```

I tried `$('.orderline .selected').next().click()` but it works only for iterating over siblings.

There is no need to manually apply `.selected`, just clicking the next element will do.

Say selected is applied to the last element in the list. Then it should find and click the first element in the list.

Comment: `$('.orderline.selected').next().click()`

Comment: I didn't know that a space could make such difference

Comment: @dfsq what about switching from last element to the first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combine the jQuery object with the first element from the `orderline` and then get the last element from the combined jQuery object.

```
$('.orderline.selected').next().add('.orderline:first').last().click();
```

```js
$('.orderline').click(function() {
  $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
})


setInterval(function() {
  $('.orderline.selected').next().add('.orderline:first').last().click();
}, 1000)
```

```css
.selected {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="orderlines">
  <li class="orderline selected">1</li>
  <li class="orderline">2</li>
  <li class="orderline">3</li>
</ul>
```

Working :

1. The `add()` method would combine with the element returned by `next()` method and the first element.
2. The element order in the result object would same as in the document so we need to get the last element from combined.
3. When it reaches the last li `next()` returns empty object and combined object only contains the first element, so `last()` would select the first element.

---

Or we need to check that `next()` returns an element or not.

```
//  get next element
var $ele = $('.orderline.selected').next();
// check empty or not, if empty get first element
if (!$ele.length) $ele = $('.orderline:first');
// fire click event
$ele.click();
```

```js
$('.orderline').click(function() {
  $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
})


setInterval(function() {
  var $ele = $('.orderline.selected').next();
  if (!$ele.length) $ele = $('.orderline:first').click();
  $ele.click();
}, 1000)
```

```css
.selected {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="orderlines">
  <li class="orderline selected">1</li>
  <li class="orderline">2</li>
  <li class="orderline">3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This isn't working. Only switch to the prev element.

Comment: Do you really need `$('.orderline.selected').next().add('.orderline:first').last().click();`? To me it seems a bit verbose. Wouldn't `$('.orderline.selected').next().click();` achieve the same result, or am I missing something?

Comment: @agrm :  read question carefully , ___"Say selected is applied to the last element in the list. Then it should find and click the first element in the list"___

Comment: Oh right, I was missing something then. Good job! :o)